# Regexp Start With Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
RegExp("^(921|931)$\\d{5,5}$").test("93111111");
```

How can I match string to start with either 921 or 931 following with 5 any digits?

Comment: /^9[23]1\d{5}/.test('93111111')

Comment: I'd suggest sticking this into a regexp workbench, such as https://regex101.com/. You'll see the notation on the right, "$ assert position at end of the string". Consider why you put that $ there and try removing it. Basically, you need to learn how to debug your own regexps. It's not really a good solution to post to SO every time you run into a little problem.

Comment: I have to wonder, what's with the downvotes? This seems like a valid question. A basic one, yes, but nonetheless valid.

Comment: "Does not show any research effort" and "not useful" both seem to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** use a regex literal like this:

```
var re = /^(9[23]1)\d{5}$/;
alert(re.test("93111111"));
```

**Explanation:**

First, remove the first `$`:

```
RegExp("^(921|931)\\d{5,5}$").test("93111111");
```

`$` only matches the end of the string, so your regex can never match when you have one after `(921|931)`. Also, please note that you need to double-escape your `\` because it is in quotes, as explained in the comments.

You can actually simplify further by simplifying `{5,5}` to `{5}`:

```
RegExp("^(921|931)\\d{5}$").test("93111111");
```

Even better, use a regex literal and simplify `(921|931)` to `(9[23]1)`:

```
var re = /^(9[23]1)\d{5}$/;
alert(re.test("93111111"));
```

This is by far the cleanest, easiest-to-read version.

Comment: if you use your regex within `"`, you need to escape backslashes one more time.

Comment: No, you just want two backslashes: `\\d`. Also, why do you show the clumsy versions using regexp constructor, and `{5,5}` first? Just show your final solution. Finally, you do not need parentheses around the `9[23]1`.

Comment: @torazaburo Sorry, editing from a mobile device is tricky. I showed the "clumsy" versions first because they are closer to what OP asked about.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I undid your substantive edit. As I'm sure you know, such edits are inappropriate here, even if they are correct and helpful. I am trying to help OP walk before he or she runs, so collapsing `(921|931)` to `(9[23]1)` without explanation frustrates that intent.

Comment: ya, that's not a mistake but `\\\\d` , without putting `^` at the start will results in incorrect match. Sorry for editing your post.

Answer (score -1):

You're close but you have an error. The `$` means match the end of a string. That means you can't have more than one since a string only has one end. Also, `{5,5}` can be simplified to just `{5}`. Try:

```
RegExp("^(921|931)\\d{5}$").test("93111111");
```

It means:

- ^ - start of the string
- Followed by 921 or 931
- Followed by 5 digits
- $ - the end of the string

Comment: Forgot to paste the extra \. It has been updated. And yes I tested it, it's called a copy/paste error. That's what I get for writing it in regex101 and pasting it here I guess...